# Proper editing support for keyboard on TreeViewer in JFace

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-plugin

I am in the process of adding editing support, but the quandary is that we are targeting JFace v 3.2, so the editing support is not available (pun intended, it is available from 3.3). Currently I can edit on mouseDown (default behaviour). Can anyone help me with a snippet (on 3.2) for keyboard editing support?

Comment: There was support for editing in JFace 3.2 using the `setCellEditors` and `setCellModifier` methods of Table/TreeViewer.

Comment: @greg-449: I know, that is how I am currently implementing my editor, but it is only activated on mouseDown. I am trying to activate on enter also